# Change the XAML Page based on the content of the webview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have an Windows 10 Universal App (C#), and I don't find how I can change to another XAML page if the webview said to change the page.

Thanks !

Comment: What have tried so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: @JimiLoe I've tried to use a function which download the WebPage of the webview and it searchs if the information for change the page is in but it's really complicated and it can't be done for page which require login access. It would be great if a WebPage could trigger a C# function or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you control the page and the page has permission to raise notifications (i.e. generated from the app with NavigateToString or https and in 
[ApplicationContentUriRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211416.aspx). See [Developing secure apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849625.aspx#validate_the_origin_of_invokescriptasync_and_postmessage_data)), the JavaScript in your page can call window.external.notify to trigger a [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) event. The Xaml page can subscribe to ScriptNotify and navigate in response to that notification.

If you just want to follow navigation within the WebView you can listen to the WebView.[NavigationStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) (etc.) events and trigger Xaml code based on that.